# setState inside a static method

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate

I want to set the state of one component from another component using setState method as it seems to involve less coding, however I have come to know that I can't use the this keyword in a static method which has created a problem for me. I would like to know another get around of this problem. help would really appreciated.

First component

```
class First extends Component {

    filterByLocation(loc) {
        const filteredData = this.state.passedInfo.filter(({area}) => area === loc);
        this.setState({members: filteredData})
    }

}
```

Second component

```
class Second extend Component {

    renderSuggestion() {

        <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress = {()=> this.setState({location}, () => {
                First.filterByLocation(this.state.location);
            })}>

            <Text> {"Click Me"}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }
}
```

Comment: One component should never set the state of another component. Instead, [lift state up]() and have it passed to the component as props, or use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and again pass the state as props, or use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context), or...

Comment: Separately: How do your two code blocks relate? The first doesn't use `Second`, and the second doesn't use `First`. Is `Home` supposed to be `First`?

Comment: yh sorry I rushed there a little, Home is suppose to be First

Answer (score 1):

I initially considered this a comment, but really, it's an answer:

One component should never set the state of another component, even if it had access to the component instance (and thus to `setState`). It certainly can't do so without access to the component instance.

Instead:

- [Lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and have it passed to the component as props, or
- Use [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) and again pass the state as props *(note: not entirely sure portals are supported in React Native, though [a search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=use+portals+in+%22react+native%22&ia=web) turns up projects providing similar functionlity)*, or
- Use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) (which [is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003209/using-context-in-react-native) in React Native)

...or possibly any of several other things. In your specific scenario, lifting state up seems like the right thing.

Comment: your answer is very good, but the components are not in a  hierarchy. First and second are completely independent from each other.

Comment: @Syed.bcc - Both the second (portals) and third (context) bullet points above work just fine when things are not in a hierarchy.

Comment: does it work with react native? I see it talks about DOM

Comment: @Syed.bcc - According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003209/using-context-in-react-native), you can use context with React Native. A [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=use+portals+in+%22react+native%22&ia=web) turns up three projects providing portals-like functionality (suggesting that actual portals may not be supported, though you might try it to see if that's really true).

Comment: thanks @Crowder all very helpful. Didn't even knew such fucntionality is possible in React

Comment: @Syed.bcc - It didn't used to be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to pass whole this object to your method like:

```
    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress = {()=> this.setState({location}, () => {
            Home.filterByLocation(this, this.state.location);
        })}>

        <Text> {"Click Me"}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Filter method:

```
    filterByLocation(context, loc) {
        const filteredData = context.state.passedInfo.filter(({area}) => area === loc);
        context.setState({members: filteredData})
    }
```

For sure it is not a good practice, it should solve the problem but should not be overused.